# Eliminar registros de tabla intermedia con EXISTS en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buen día compañeros, actualmente deseo realizar una eliminación de registros de una tabla llamada `VTST` (tabla intermedia), pero solo voy a eliminar aquellos registros que se encuentren en las `CUSR` y `PROT` (tablas destino), lo relaciono todo con la tabla `GIMT` (tabla origen) ya que es la que tiene relación con esas tablas destino y la intermedia, repito la tabla intermedia (VTST) no se relaciona con las tablas destino, anexo estructura de tablas:

**Tabla ORIGEN GIMT**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tablas DESTINO CURS y PROT**:

**PROT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CURS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Intermedia (donde se desea eliminar los registros):

**VTST**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo mi consulta:

```
delete from VTST
where EXISTS (
  select * from GIMT 
  inner join CURS
  ON GIMT.org_id= CURS.org_id AND GIMT.user_id = CURS.user_id AND CURS.R_CRE_ID = 'DATA'
  inner join PROT
  ON UPPER(TRIM(GIMT.principal_id))= TRIM(PROT.principal_id) AND PROT.R_CRE_ID = 'DATA'
);
```

Mi pregunta/duda es: 
¿Esta correcta la consulta? ¿Como es que actúa el EXISTS para eliminar solo los registros que relacionan la tabla Origen y Destino? ¿Que campos toma como referencia para eliminar los registros?

**NOTA**: Soy nuevo en Oracle y me basé en posts y tutoriales para llegar a esta consulta.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No. no es correcta. eso va a borrar toda la tabla VTST, porque exist solo verifica que la subconsulta devuelva algo, no que devuelve. Tal vez podrias adjuntar un grafico que ayude a entender las relaciones, y un ejemplo de datos de todas las tablas y cuales se deberian borrar? Aparte, agregar en el join clausulas del where tampoco es correcto. Las clausulas del join deben ser las condiciones del join. y principal_id no es un numero? si no es un numero, algo esta bastante raro ahi. y hacer un upper del trim tambien.. puede ser que se hayan guardado de diferente forma?

Comment: Enterado, en cuanto a tus preguntas: principal_id no es un número, es un nombre de usuario (si confunde el nombre de la columna), en cuanto el UPPER y el TRIM los usé debido a que la data también contenía espacios en blanco en la tabla origen y en las destino No contaba con espacios en blanco y estaba en mayúsculas, eran el mismo usuario. En algún punto del flujo de la aplicación debió hacer esos cambios.

Comment: En un momento agregaré más información, sería de mucha ayuda y te lo agradecería si me pudieras orientar un poco @gbianchi.

Comment: Edita la pregunta con esta info. usar el nombre de usuario como clave de la tabla es un gran NO.

Comment: Te comento que el nombre de usuario (principal_id) es por el campo que se me pidió que se relacionara, al parecer es el único campo con el que se relacionan... Me da a entender que no se puede repetir el nombre de usuario.

Comment: y no por eso tiene que ser clave de la tabla.. y menos de otra tabla tambien, donde para colmo esta mal guardado...

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón, estoy algo confundido solamente. Ya actualicé la pregunta con la estructura de las tablas.

Comment: Cabe mencionar @gbianchi que se me pide eliminar los registros de la tabla intermedia específicamente aquellos que coincidan con la relación de la tabla origen con las destino por medio del join que realicé.

Comment: olvidate de ese join.. esto es mucho mas simple si entiendo bien. hay una sola relacion aca entre VSTS y GIMT? y luego GIMT conecta con las otras dos? es asi?

Comment: Pues si @gbianchi , el campo CORP_ID de la tabla VTST es exactamente los mismo que el campo ORG_ID de la tabla origen GIMT. Y sí, GIMT conecta con las otras 2 tablas destino, una por medio del USER_ID y ORG_ID y la otra por medio del Principal_ID.

Comment: Voy a armarte una respuesta, pero es probable que tengamos que ir tuneandola porque no se si entiendo todas las relaciones correctamente.. pero vayamos probando...

Comment: Enterado, gracias por tu ayuda. Iré probando para informarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo que hay que borrar es de la tabla VTST, y esta se conecta con la tabla GIMT solamente, necesitamos saber los ORG_ID de la tabla GIMT que existen en las dos tablas hijas..

Para ello, vamos a armar una query que solo devuelva los ORG_ID que cumplan esa condicion, o sea, tener registros en las dos tablas hijas.

```
select GIMT.org_id
from GIMT 
  inner join CURS ON GIMT.org_id= CURS.org_id AND GIMT.user_id = CURS.user_id
  inner join PROT ON UPPER(TRIM(GIMT.principal_id))= TRIM(PROT.principal_id)
where CURS.R_CRE_ID = 'DATA' and PROT.R_CRE_ID = 'DATA'
```

Esta tabla, deberia devolver solamente los org_id que cumplen todas las condiciones que pedimos.

Luego, la consulta de delete, solamente deberia borrar esos org_id, y para ello alcanza con hacer

```
delete from VTST
where org_id in (toda la consulta anterior)
```

Comment: Disculpa, tengo una duda @gbianchi, me muestra el siguiente error cuando realizo el primer select: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined". Sin embargo cambio el org_id por el * para que me traiga todos los datos y funciona. Tienes idea de por qué sucede esto?

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, al parecer debo indicar a que tabla le hace referencia el campo org_id, ejemplo: GIMT.org_id ... Estoy en lo correcto?... Esto debido a que el campo org_id se encuentra en más de una tabla.

Comment: estas en lo correcto @BDOM. hay que indicar la tabla.. ahora lo modifico...

Comment: Enterado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @gbianchi.